# How can I send my username and password to a server when requesting it for some data?

Tags: node.js, authentication, npm, request, fetch

I want to retrieve some data from a server and when I visit the server's site, I am prompted for my username and password like in the image attached.

[image]

I want to write some code that will do this for me. However, I have not found a solution that works.

I've tried the **request** and **node-fetch** modules with no success.

```
var url = 'http://' + username + ':' + password + '@some.server.com/data';
request({url: url}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the 
  response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

```
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
request(
  {
    url : url,
    headers : {
      "Authorization" : auth,
      'sendImmediately': false
    }
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    // Do more stuff with 'body' here
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML
  }
);
```

```
fetch('some.server.com/data',
  {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      redirect: 'follow',
      agent: null,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
      },
      timeout: 5000
  })
  .then(function(response){
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(text){
    console.log('Request success: ' + text);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request error: ' + error);
  });
```

How can I insert the username and password within the code so that the data retrieval process is automated? Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to inspect the request when you do it with your browser. Then you'll get the request type (post, get, ... ?) and you'll be able to see if the credentials are set in headers, in url or in the body of the request.

Comment: Are you sure the server uses Basic authentication? Have you tried using the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you're using `Basic Auth` then try this

```
request(
  {
    url : url,
    auth: {                     <============ This
      user: username,              
      password: password
    }
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    // Do more stuff with 'body' here
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML
  }
);
```